# Can we draw on top of listing with TikZ?

Tags: diagrams

[image]

I want to replicate a diagram like this. I will have the code (a `Listing`) on the left side, and rectangle with lines connecting to a table on the right side. Is this possible to do with TikZ?

Comment: Have a look at the [tikzmark](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) package. If you want someone to help you, you'll need to first post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to give people something to work with.

Comment: Alternatively, you could put the listing inside a tikz node (asuming it is not a float).

Comment: To follow up on @314159265358979323's comment, there is an extension to tikzmark that adds bucket loads of tikzmarks to listings code, see the documentation for details. There are also examples on this site, such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/657454/86

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great to have some code to work with, preferably a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). There are different ways to produce a code block as you show in your picture and ways how to overlay this as you intend depend on which packages you use. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: This answer was helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40715